# How do I start a container on Eclipse Kanto from a remote client?

Tags: eclipse-iot

I would like to spin up an OCI container on an edge device running Eclipse Kanto.

I tried to find some documentation or quick start guide describing how to do that on the Kanto project website but didn't find anything.

Do I need to send a particular command message to Kanto via the cloud connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at the [Getting started Kanto documentation - Explore via Eclipse Hono](https://websites.eclipseprojects.io/kanto/docs/getting-started/hono/). The scenario there is exactly spinning up an OCI container remotely via Eclipse Kanto at the edge.